# ListView not appearing / Android Layouts

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a textView, editText, and listView. I would like to order the textView and editText next to each other, hence the LinearLayout. Additionally, create a listView under them. Here's the XML.

Unfortunately, the listView doesn't show up. I made sure the ArrayList I'm using is not empty.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" 
   android:gravity="center"
   android:background ="#268496" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/prefixText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:typeface="sans" />

 <EditText
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:divider="#CCCCCC"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp" >

   </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Creating the list:

```
public void listView (){
     ListView lv;
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("foo");
     your_array_list.add("bar");
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Linear Layout height is match_parent, change that to wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" 
   android:gravity="center"
   android:background ="#268496" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/prefixText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:typeface="sans" />

 <EditText
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:divider="#CCCCCC"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp" >

   </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of match_parent for your `LinearLayout`  use wrap_content
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `LinearLayout` is having `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and that means it will have full height and there by will not leave space for ListView.

So replace it with `wrap_content`.